# ffmpeg warning and no sound on the encoding video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

i try to convert a dvd to mp4 with ffmpeg (on windows) but i have some warning message AND i have no sound on the converted video

i use this cli :

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -i VTS_01_1.vob -vf yadif -c:v h264_qsv -global_quality 15 -preset medium -c:a aac -b:a 256k VTS_01_0.mp4
```

information on the video

```
ffmpeg -i .\VTS_01_1.VOB

Input #0, mpeg, from '.\VTS_01_1.VOB':
  Duration: 00:24:55.52, start: 0.360000, bitrate: 5742 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
  Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bottom first), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7000000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:2[0xa0]: Audio: pcm_dvd, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

but i have this warning msg :

- WARNING: defaulting hwaccel_output_format to qsv for compatibility with old commandlines. This behaviour is DEPRECATED and will be removed in the future. Please explicitly set "-hwaccel_output_format qsv".
- WARNING: defaulting child_device_type to AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_DXVA2 for compatibility with old commandlines. This behaviour will be removed in the future. Please explicitly set device type via "-init_hw_device" option.

can you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Steps needed to fix the problem:

1. Add `-hwaccel_output_format qsv` before `-i`
2. Add `-init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=dxva2` before `-i`

Modified version of your command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -init_hw_device qsv:hw,child_device_type=dxva2 -i VTS_01_1.vob -vf yadif -c:v h264_qsv -global_quality 15 -preset medium -c:a aac -b:a 256k VTS_01_0.mp4
```